# Debezium Outbox Pattern property transforms.outbox.table.expand.json.payload remove empty arrays

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm implementing an outbox pattern using the debezium postgres connector, building up upon the official documentation: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/outbox-event-router.html.

Evething ok but now I see strange behevior that empty array are missing in kafka messages if
`transforms.outbox.table.expand.json.payload` 
tern to true

if in table I have value "{"some":"test", "agreemets":[]}" in topic message looks {"some":"test"}.

first line if we set to false
second line if we set to true

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHvIf.png)

How to prevent removeing empty arrays?

My full Kafka connect config

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "db",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.dbname": "mycbh_dev",
    "database.server.name": "db",
    "schema.include.list": "common",
    "table.include.list": "common.outboxmessages",
    "tombstones.on.delete": "false",
    "transforms": "outbox",
    "transforms.outbox.type": "io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter",
    "transforms.outbox.route.by.field": "topic",
    "transforms.outbox.route.topic.replacement": "${routedByValue}",
    "transforms.outbox.table.field.event.timestamp": "created_at",
    "transforms.outbox.table.expand.json.payload": "true",
    "transforms.outbox.tracing.with.context.field.only": "true",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput"
}
```

Comment: You don't refer to which connector version you're using; however there have been some fixes in recent builds to JSON expansion within the outbox SMT, so please the latest Debezium builds.

Comment: @Naros I used version `2.1.3.Final`